# How to only edit certain strings in column?

Tags: mysql, sql, dremio

I have table in a sql table that looks like this:

```
column
1
2
welcome from henry
welcome from beth
welcome
3
4
```

How do I only edit the values that have 'Welcome from' to become only 'Welcome'?

New column:

```
1
2
welcome
welcome
welcome
3
4
```

I can not edit the table, have to do this in select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
UPDATE tab
SET col = 'welcome'
WHERE col LIKE 'welcome %'
```

---

**EDIT:**

> Unfortunately I cant update any tables, I can only do it select statements

```
SELECT CASE WHEN col LIKE 'welcome %' THEN 'welcome' ELSE col END AS col
FROM tab
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cant update any tables, I can only do it select statements.

Comment: @RustyShackleford That's not a problem

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET column_name = 'VALUE YOU WANTS TO ADD IN PLACE OF OLD'
WHERE column_name LIKE 'old_value %;'
```